# Integral of series. What do I need?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, summation

I'am preparing for mathematical analysis exam. I have one excercise to do; calculate:
$$ \int^\infty_3 \sum^\infty_{n=0} \frac{(-2x)^{n+1}}{n!} \,dx $$

I don't know even wehere to start... I suppose here's some 'popular' sum etc. but how to approach this without knowing it?

Comment: It should be enough to recall that $e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} $.

Comment: moorzyn  Please [read this post: How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/9003), and in particular, [read this answer about avoiding "I have no clue/I don't know where to start" questions.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/9003)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should recognize the resemblance between your series $\displaystyle\sum^\infty_{n=0} \frac{(-2x)^{n+1}}{n!}$ and the well known series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a^n}{n!} = e^a.$

You have $a^{n+1}$ in the numerator instead of $a^n,$ so write
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a^{n+1}}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a\cdot \frac{a^n}{n!}.
$$
The factor $a$ does not change as $n$ goes from $0$ to $\infty,$ so it can be pulled out:
$$
= a\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a^n}{n!} = ae^a.
$$
Then you have
$$
\int_3^\infty (-2x)e^{-2x} \, dx
$$
Then you can integrate by parts.

Comment: Thank you, already solved (comment below) :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** 
$$e^z=\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n!}$$

Comment: So, the sum from my question is $$ \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(-2x)^1\frac{(-2x)^n}{n!} = -2xe^{-2x} $$?

Comment: @moorzyn exactly, the rest is just integration by parts

Comment: Integral is a piece of cake now. Thank you!